# iOS remote debugging on distributed build

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile-safari

When building an app through Xcode, all the UIWebViews appear as inspectable applications in Safari, but when archiving and signing for distribution, it seems that functionality is lost (probably for safety-reasons).

But alas, I have this scenario where I'm building a test-environment for web developers who rely on being able to debug their content, and it will be distributed to a multitude of devices as an ad-hoc distributed package.

Is there any way to re-enable remote debugging on an archived build, through a configuration-setting, or anything of the likes?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the Web Inspector when the app was installed by Xcoode not OTA using HockeyApp. But you could try opening the content you want to Inspect in Mobile Safari.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

> Important: You can only inspect apps on devices that have been
>   transferred to your device from Xcode. You cannot inspect apps that
>   have been downloaded from the App Store, even if it is your app.

Comment: your link seems dead?

Comment: Thanks @DotNetWise Apple created a Safari Web Inspector Guide and killed the old page.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use [TestFlightSDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/).

Hope it helps)

Comment: We're currently using HockeySDK for distribution. Does TestFlight offer anything regarding remote web-debugging in particular?

Comment: If i don't mistaken, it provide crash reports even after uploading app to AppStore.